# how to bind the value properly to a angular dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I thought I understood how to do this but my angular dropdown is not putting the value into my control as expected. I am getting value set to 0 when it should be 2005.

2015

// array
vm.years = [thisYear, thisYear - 1, thisYear - 2, thisYear - 3, thisYear - 4, thisYear - 5, thisYear - 6, thisYear - 7, thisYear - 8, thisYear - 9];

```
 <select name="row.endYear" data-ng-model="row.endYear" ng-options="I give up" class="form-control" id="endYear" required data-z-validate>
                    <option value="">End Year *</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Post what you have instead of `I give up` - `ng-options="value as text for item in array"`

Comment: I laughed at the `i give up`

Answer (score 0):

You need to populate the dropdown `ng-options` similar to `ng-repeat`. Please refer to this. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions